# How to design this API Translation module

Tags: node.js, express, backend

How to design this API
Translation module: This module can translate English, Arabic, and Dutch languages. It will translate all strings within the app and make all strings resource dynamic
I am able to make api in which I give any input the language of that input will change
But how to make for whole app?

I am able to make api in which I give any input the language of that input will change
But how to make for whole app?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.